# Why don't my nodes in Fez have pictures on them?

Tags: fez

I play Fez on PC. When I get the ability to check the world map, all the nodes are blank, like no pictures. You can still make them gold, they just don't have any pictures. I don't know if this is a bug or not, because I can't find any articles about this.

Comment: Please try to limit yourself to one question per question. You can edit your question using the edit button below the tags. It's easier to search and answer that way. Thank you.

Comment: One post, one question. I've removed your extra question—please submit it as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

If you run the game on machine with Intel HD GPU, you may experience this bug. According to game changelog, it has been fixed in version 1.04.